# Array of checkboxes and readonly text fields

Tags: javascript, checkbox, readonly

I have an array of checkboxes and text fields. what i want to achieve is that when the checkbox is not checked the input type text field is readonly but when the checkbox is checked, the input type text field is no longer read only.

```
<?php 
$rsi = pg_query("Select * From items Order by name;");
while ($ri = pg_fetch_array($rsi, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><input id="item" class="input_control" type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="<?php echo $ri['item_no']; ?>"></td>
<td class="qty" align="center"><input id="quantity" type="text" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo $rsview['quantity'];?>"></td>
<td ><?php echo $ri['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ri['model']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ri['brand']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ri['item_type']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function toggleTB(myCheckbox){ 
    if(myCheckbox.checked){
        document.myForm.myField.disabled=1
    } 
    else{
        document.myForm.myField.disabled=0
    }
 } 
</script> 

<form name="myForm"> 
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleTB(this)">
    <input type="text" name="myField" value="asdf"> 
</form>
```

Comment: That is not how my code looks like. There will be multiple checkboxes and if user checks on the checkbox he/she will be able to type on the input text field. if for example users checks 5 checkboxes, users can also type on the 5 text fields. And i need to process what the user's typed on the input field by using array name=qty[]

Comment: You can still pass the name of your text field as second parameter

Comment: How? i don't understand. i am so noob with javascript

Comment: can you please use the first code i posted and enter the changes please? i don't wan't to break my code as there is a css style attached to it.

Comment: can anyone please help me with this?